# Is there a way to redirect output to external console from NLog in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, logging, console, nlog

I just started using NLog in my asp.net application, and I need to see log messages in real time. When I run it in VS2010 I can look at VS output window, but when I run it on the test box I obviously don't have that option. What I need is when my asp.net app starts a console window should open and show log entries in real time.

Any idea how I could accomplish that?

P.S. Of course, I could output to a file, and have some console application monitor changes to the file and show them, but I'm hoping for some easier/existing solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [Sentinel](http://sentinel.codeplex.com/).  I had some trouble getting it connected directly to NLog, so I just had NLog output to file and used Sentinel to view the file.